# How can i check if the specific strings exist in a List<string> and if not to remove the indexs from the List?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I tried this but this is not working.
I'm getting index out of bound exception.

```
for (int x = 0; x < newText.Count; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < WordsList.words.Length; y++)
    {
        if (!newText[x].Contains(WordsList.words[y]))
        {
            for (int n = 0; n < 3; n++)
                newText.RemoveAt(x);
        }
    }
}
```

newText is a List
words is string[]

newText format is like this:

```
index 0 = this is a text hello all
index 1 = time&date (6/14/2014....)
index 2 = empty ""

index 3 = text hello world
index 4 = time&date (6/14/2014....)
index 5 = empty ""
```

And so on...

What i want to do is to loop over newText and if in index 0 there no any word(string) from words then remove index 0,1,2 next itertion check index 3 for any words if not exist one word or more remove indexs 3,4,5.

If in index 0 or 3 there is one word or more then do nothing dont remove anything.
In the end newText should be in the same format as before:

```
index 0 text line
index 1 date&time
index 2 empty ""
```

Just the new newText content will be with text lines that contain one ore more strings from words.

EDIT

This is what i tried now:
First this is how i build the List:

```
List<string> t = filterNumbers(text);
            for (int i = 0; i < t.Count; i++)
            {
                if (!newText.Contains(t[i]))
                {
                    newText.Add(t[i]);
                    newText.Add(dateTime[i]);
                    newText.Add("");
                }
            }
```

Removing numbers and leave only text and add it.
In the end in this case i have in newText 150 indexs. That's 50 indexs of text lines.

Then i tried this:

```
int lastindex = newText.Count - 1;
            for (int i = newText.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < WordsList.words.Length; x++)
                {
                    if (!newText[i].Contains(WordsList.words[x]))
                    {
                        if (i != lastindex)
                        {
                            newText.RemoveAt(i + 1);
                        }
                        newText.RemoveAt(i);
                    }
                }
            }
```

But i'm getting exception on the line:

```
if (!newText[i].Contains(WordsList.words[x]))
```

Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection

EDIT

[image: spaces and line in the end]

Comment: The `RemoveAt` calls you are making on `newText` is taking away the element at `i`.  Then the next time it loops on `x` you are out of bounds.

Comment: The logic of your edited answer is completely controversial to your initial question. If it compiled you would face the problem that you would remove more than twice as many lines as you initially planned because you do not check only the "important" lines but rather every line which leads to over 100 deleted lines because the string ``""``, which appears 50 times in your code, does not contain any of the words and would be deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly that you wanted to check whether a specific line contains some words and if not remove that and the two following lines, here is a possible solution:

```
// start at the bottom in the first line "that matters" and go down by 3
for (int x = newText.Count - 3; x >= 0; x-=3) 
{
    // check if the line contains any of the words specified
    if (!WordsList.words.Any(w => newText[x].Contains(w)) || newText[x] == "") 
    {
        // remove the checked line as well as the next two if not
        l.RemoveRange(x, 3); 
    }
}
```

### EDIT

Corrected the predicate to:

```
!WordsList.words.Any(w => newText[x].Contains(w));
```

from

```
!WordsList.words.Any(w => newText.Contains(w));
```

### EDIT 2

Added the empty string as possibility

The problem was that if the line to test was empty, it would pass the test because it does not contain any word from `WordsList.words`. The test now includes the empty string as an option and removes it when encountered.

Comment: This solution return empty List. It remove al the indexs/lines. And i checked at least one word i saw in the website exist also in the words list.

Comment: @user3739928 My bad I made a big mistake :D It should be corrected now!

Comment: ThreeFx it's working almost good. The filtering is ok but in the end i see 3 spaces and a date&time line. So in the last the line is date&time that's ok but then after it there three empty lines and another line after of date&time. And in the end it should be only date&time line.

Comment: ThreeFx i have updated my question now i added a screenshot and marked the area with the problem in black square. you can the last line is date&time but then after it there are more 2-3 empty lines and after them another date&time line. The format should be allways the first index a text line the last one date&time.

Comment: @user3739928 Fixed it, the problem was the empty string

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your logic:

```
(1)    for (int i = newText.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
       {
(2)        for (int x = 0; x < WordsList.words.Length; x++)
           {
               if (...)
               {
(3)                 newText.RemoveAt(i);
               }
           }
       }
```

You can see that even if you removed lines in (3), you continue loop in (2) which can try again remove line in (2) for *new* indexes, which now become out of bounds

you need to add `break` after (3) to continue loop (1)

Comment: This still does not remove 3 lines as the author wanted

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems your data structure is really bad. Anyway if you have to keep the structure as is I think this can work :

```
var  newList = new List<string>();
for (int index = 0; index < newText.Count; index = index + 3)
{
    if (WordsList.Any(t => newText[index].ToLower().Trim().Contains(t.ToLower().Trim())))
    {
        newList.AddRange(newText.Skip(index).Take(3));
    }
}

newText = newList;
```

Comment: Use ``newText.AddRange(index, 3)`` for more legibility

Comment: Same this solution: This solution return empty List. It remove al the indexs/lines. And i checked at least one word i saw in the website exist also in the words list.

Comment: I think strings of WordsList.words are not exactly the same as string in the first index of newText. Maybe it's something to see with case sensitive or space or encoding. try with ToLower Trim. I edited my solution with that.

Comment: Maybe you right. The strings/words are all in hebrew also the text in newText is in hebrew so maybe encoding is needed ? I know in form1 constructor first time i download the html file of the website i need to encode it: client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1255); so maybe there must be encoing here too ?

Comment: Enconding is a pain for me. Can you try this on your downloaded html string ? byte[] bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding(1255).GetBytes(downloadedHtmlString);
            var newString = Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes); and tell me if it work

Answer (score 0):

```
// For each 3-word-sets
for (int x = 0; x < newText.Count; x += 3)
{
   // For each word in that 3-word-set
   for (int k = x; k < 3; k++)
   {
      // Check each word
      bool breakOut = false;
      for (int y = 0; y < WordsList.words.Length; y++)
      {
         if (!newText[k].Contains(WordsList.words[y]))
         {
            newText.RemoveAt(x+2);
            newText.RemoveAt(x+1);
            newText.RemoveAt(x);
            x -= 3;
            breakOut = true;
            break;
         }
      }
      if (breakOut) { break; }
   }
}
```

I just wanted to test and experiment with your original code. Haven't tested this. Just make sure the list contains 3×n items.